# global settings for the fileExtension configuration option

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

Is it possible to create a global configuration setting? For example, I want all of my clasp pull/clone commands to use `.js`. I know I can do this by setting the `fileExtension` property in the `.clasp.json` in the project directory but then I have to set it for each file. Is it possible to set it globally somewhere, like maybe in the `.clasprc.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.clasprc.json` file is the file used to store the Apps Script credentials and API tokens, so it is not a configuration file. I haven't seen anything related to this in the github [documentation](https://github.com/google/clasp). The closest solution as you know is editing the Project Settings File (`.clasp.json`).